# What is the Meaning of "The report goes on to note that"

Tags: sentence-meaning

What is the meaning of report goes on to note that in simple speech?

The report goes on to note that even though the use of the riskiest pesticides has declined nationwide, they still make up more than 40 percent of all pesticides used today

Answer (score 1):

The author of the sentence is summarizing all or part of **the report**. The author chooses the word **note** to indicate that something is a fact, not an opinion. The word also suggests that the information is not central to the idea of the report. Many authors are sloppy with their choice of reporting verbs, however, so it is possible that the **40 percent of all pesticides** idea really is central to the report.

You may use phrases like **goes on to note** only when you have *already* summarized part of the document. You cannot introduce your first idea with this phrase.

The phrase also indicates the relative position of this idea and the previous idea. In the **report** being summarized, the point about **40 percent of all pesticides** comes *after* the idea that was previously summarized. You cannot summarize information on Page 3 and use **goes on to note** to introduce information on Page 1. But again, many authors are sloppy about this rule.